# Mac os X PHP56 ApcU via Brew - Symbol not found: _zend_signal_globals

Tags: php, macos, apcu

When trying to install APCu via brew I get the error

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/opt/php56-apcu/apcu.so' - dlopen(/usr/local/opt/php56-apcu/apcu.so, 9): 
>   Symbol not found: _zend_signal_globals
>   Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/php56-apcu/apcu.so
>   Expected in: flat namespace
>    in /usr/local/opt/php56-apcu/apcu.so in Unknown on line 0

This occurs no matter how I install APCu

```
brew install php56-apcu
brew install --build-from-source php56-apcu
brew install php56-apcu --enable-apc-bc
```

APC fails to appear in `phpinfo` too.

Opcache is install fine, as is `php-intl`

Comment: no disrespect, but got to ask : what do `which php` and `php -v` reveal? so easy to miss a few crucial steps on OSX.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg version is 5.6.24 and /usr/bin/php (I think, I'm away from my machine right now)

Comment: /usr/bin/php would necessarily be the apple distribution php on El-Capitan (cant be certain about previous versions, OSX is such a moving target). Try to add `/usr/local/bin` as top dog in your path (.bash_profile) and retry in a newly instantiated terminal window.

Comment: That has sorted it. I have posted a follow up now because apache is ignoring my brew php version http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39721251/forcing-apache2-to-use-php56-from-homebrew thanks again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the executable in `/usr/bin/php` would necessarily be the apple distribution php on El-Capitan (cant be certain about previous versions, OSX is such a moving target).

Try to add /usr/local/bin as top dog in your path (in file `.bash_profile`) and retry in a newly instantiated terminal window.