# Forcing Apache2 to use php56 from Homebrew

Tags: php, apache2, homebrew, apc

So I started with

```
brew reinstall php56 --with-apache
```

This worked fine I then amended `httpd.conf` to include

```
LoadModule php5_module /usr/local/opt/php56/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```

But upon inspection of `phpinfo` its using PHP 5.6.24 which is wrong, thats the MacOS native version. The brew version is 5.6.26.

For some reason my Apache2 config is being ignored - or I have amended the wrong file. The one I changed as in `/etc/apche2/httpd.conf`

This is a follow on from my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39708271/mac-os-x-php56-apcu-via-brew-symbol-not-found-zend-signal-globals) related to getting APCu working. Its working for the brew version of PHP but is not working for the the native PHP version. Therefore I want to force Apache2 to use the brew version with APCu.

Comment: are you running the distribution apache ? and, are you using `php-fpm` ? And, did you restart apache ?

Comment: Apache is the native Apple install, its not been install via brew - or at least its not in `brew list`. Apache has been restarted. And not using `php-fpm` as far as I know.

Comment: try to hardwire it ... this is how I do it for my current install :  `LoadModule php5_module    /usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.38/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so`. Dont forget to restart apache. I will be back later.

Comment: Hardwiring to `/usr/local/Cellar/php56/5.6.26_2/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so` hasn't done anything after restating apache with `sudo apachectl restart`. If its still using the 5.6.24 version I am thinking it just plain ignoring my config? Because the old reference I have commented out completely `#LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so` so how is it still working at all?

Comment: Restarting my machine fixed it! What the?!

Comment: That is appleDogmaInAbox for you : because of SIP, they have apachectl completely tributary to LaunchControl ... if you ever find that you are stuck with the brain-dead apple-apache and need to brew apache, post another question, i will spell-out for you how to nuke the distro apache (not an easy one).

Comment: I have considered that, then didn't because it seemed like a massive task

Comment: next time you need to change httpd configs, instead of rebooting try to `killall httpd`, LaunchControl will restart it immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was restarting apache, but it was not working it turns out.

Restarting my whole machine did work and apache then used the correct version of PHP.

Apparently `killall httpd` has the same effect too. Although I have not tried that.

Comment: **[Andy tried it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39790275/php-ini-extension-directory-not-working?noredirect=1#comment66875256_39790275)** and it worked for him:)