# Php.ini extension directory not working

Tags: php, macos, apache, server

In my php.ini file i have setup on Mac OSX i've added in an an extension directory:

```
extension_dir = "/usr/local/php5/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226"
```

I've restarted apache and noticed that it isn't using this address instead:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/php56/5.6.26_2/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226
```

Now i'm 100% sure im in the correct php.ini files as i checked the php info and it says `/private/etc/apache2/php.ini`

I'm trying to get mcrypt installed which is in the first directory, am i looking at the wrong ini file? Or am i being silly and writing something incorrectly?

What am i missing?

Comment: how did you restart apache ? OSX apache or your own ? OSX version ?

Comment: used : sudo apachectl restart - osx: 10.12 - osx apache

Comment: try `sudo killall httpd` ... if you are using El-Capitan with the OSX distro, LaunchControl will restart it automagically.  If not **[this might be related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39721251/forcing-apache2-to-use-php56-from-homebrew?noredirect=1#comment66745023_39721251)**

Comment: ah , 10.12, well I am not certain. I am postponing as long as possible until i finish a current project. Each OSX breaks my dev pipeline and i end up dead in water for a period. My previous comment may not apply.

Comment: Yeah, updating screwed me, i totally forgot about it >_<

Comment: sudo killall httpd and then sudo apachectl start worked, thanks so much :) if you want to put that in an answer YvesLeBorg i'll mark it up :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo killall httpd
```

and then

```
sudo apachectl start
```

fixed my problem, Thanks to  YvesLeBorg for the info.